# How do you change an HTML radiobutton selection from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

I need to select an HTML radiobutton (deselecting any previously selected radiobutton) on my form, from within Javascript.

How is this accomplished?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you set the "checked" property to `true` on one radio button, the other button with the same name is automatically unchecked.

Thus,

```
document.getElementById('buttonX').checked = true;
```

will cause "buttonY" to be unchecked if the HTML looks like:

```
<input type='radio' id='buttonX' name='fred' value='X'>
<input type='radio' id='buttonY' name='fred' value='Y' checked>
```

**edit** Remember that "radio buttons" have that name because on old radios (not necessarily older than me) the station preset buttons were mechanically inter-linked such that exactly one button was pressed at all times. Fiddling with the buttons to get them all to be un-pressed was a fun but risky pastime, as most adults didn't appreciate the aesthetic appeal of a row of un-pressed radio buttons all neatly aligned.

Comment: Property, not attribute. If you were setting the attribute then the value would be `checked`, not `true`.

Comment: Well OK; property, attribute, I guess it makes a difference.